# MySQL: PK give error when updated even though FK CONSTRAINT is set to ON UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, error-handling, sql-update

I'm using MySQL and I am trying to change the value of one of my PK attributes. The FK connected to it is set up with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. When I try to change the PK value, I get the following error:

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_family_finance`.`items`, CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `items` (`item`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

As you can see, the error message even states that it is set to `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. Why would I be getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: You would get this error if a column in the cascade chain violates the foreign key constraint.  For instance, a referenced column might be part of a composite foreign key.

Comment: Please post related tables structure in order to have specific answers. The output of mysqldump for the related tables would be good